# Unsupported operand type for NoneType and str

Tags: python

I get a message that states:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/www/fosa/error_supressor.py", line 46, in <module>
   sys.stderr.write(latest + '\n')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I have been trying to solve this problem for days now but honestly I'm a rocky programmer.
So let's line up the problem and see if there is a patient person that can spare some time solving a humble stranger's problem :-)

Besides that when I check my error log I find this error message, which I suspect is related:

```
File "/var/www/fosa/app/controllers/client/client.py", line 601, in detail
    if not course.bookable or not course.school.partner.active: # both objects are boolean 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bookable'
```

Comment: What do you do to get the error? Is it code you wrote? Can you post the code the gives the error?

Comment: Did you write these files? If so, give us the relevant sections of them, please.

Comment: a quick glance tels me that you need to do something like sys.stderr.write(str(latest) + '\n')  because latest is not a string. but abit of code posted here might help

Comment: @Bram: Yes, converting to string may be a good debug strategy at the very least.

Answer (score 4):

- Something is binding `None` to `latest`. Figure out what it is and fix your logic error.
- Something is binding `None` to `course`. Figure etc.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously from the traceback, one has:
- `latest` is None
- `course` is None

A common pattern in python is to have variable names always be bound to a unique type, except when the most meaningful value that one can assign is a 'null' value, in which case you'd make the variable equal to `None`. E.g. say `get(pk)` returns an object from the DB, but it returns `None` when there's no object for the key `pk`. To fix the bug i'd do this:

Write something such as:

```
if latest is None:
     # do something
else:
     sys.stderr.write(latest + '\n')
```

or maybe

```
sys.stderr.write('%s\n' % latest) #so that latest can be of any type
```

instead of

```
sys.stderr.write(latest + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. As you have probably guessed I have not written this code. I ended up using this advise: sys.stderr.write(latest + '\n'). There was champagne but......

Now I get a new error and I haven't done anything except changing that code in error_supressor:
  File "/var/www/fosa/app/dispatcher.py", line 47, in redirect_course_detail
    '?valuta=' + str(currency_id), 301)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_detail_url'

I'm not sure what code to show cause these 3 errors must be related and they are in different files, different objects...